# Why does rich:inputNumberSlider does not update backing bean (@Managed Bean)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

The `inputNumberSlider` of Richfaces fails in my case to immediately update the backing bean. The setter method is never invoked. I'm right in saying, that backing bean field should should be updated on change?

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider 
id="severityLevel" 
value="#{pubController.severityLevel}"
minValue="1" 
maxValue="3" 
maxlength="1" />
```

I did set a breakpoint in the setter method, but it never rises. I must say, it works properly for all the `h:inputText` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setSecurityLevel` setter will never be invoked till you submit the form where your `rich:inputNumberSlider` is contained.

Alternatively, you can set the value whenever the `inputNumberSlider` is changed, adding an ajax per event processing, which will execute your component (I don't use richfaces, but that would be the desired format):

```
<h:form>
    <rich:inputNumberSlider id="severityLevel" value="#{pubController.severityLevel}"
        minValue="1" maxValue="3" maxlength="1" >
        <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" />
    </rich:inputNumberSlider>
</h:form>
```

Generally, that kind of behaviour is unrequired unless you want to perform some kind of validation while user is changing the input value (it also could be useful to [render dependent components](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=ajax&sample=selectsUpdates&skin=blueSky)). In most of the cases the validation is performed over all the components once you post the whole form.

Comment: I have forms where no save buttons exists - direct editing. In this case your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!